# Unique closed-form Formula for Area of Intersection between two Circles with known Radii and Distance between their centers

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

I am interested in finding a closed-form formula to calculate the area of intersection between two circles with known radii, $r_1$ and $r_2$, where $r_1 \geq r_2$, and a known distance $d$ between their centers. Importantly, I need this formula to work even in scenarios where the distance $d$ exceeds the sum of the radii $r_1 + r_2$, or is less than their difference $r_1 - r_2$.

I have searched online for solutions, but most of them do not account for cases where $d$ exceeds the sum of the radii ($d \geq r_1 + r_2$) or is less than their difference ($d \leq r_1 - r_2$). For example, solutions like the one shown in https://dassencio.org/102 do not work in these scenarios.

Can someone provide such a formula or suggest an approach to derive it? Any insights or references to existing solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How can $d>r_1+r_2$ and they have intersection.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, when $d\le r_1-r_2$, then the intersection is the whole smaller circle with area $\pi r_2^2$?

Comment: The link you posted actually covers all three cases. Look at the bottom of the page.

If what you mean is that three separate cases do not constitute "a single formula" then that doesn't make sense. "if a < b then c else d" is a perfectly valid formula.

Comment: Maybe this link can be useful to understand what I'm looking for: <https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-overlapping-area-of-two-circles>. In Glenn Clemens' answer, a formula is derived for calculating the overlapping area of two circles of which the distance $d$ of the centers and the two radii $R$ and $r$ are known, where $R \geq r$. The final formula is: 

$$ A = \frac{1}{2}R^2(2\theta-\sin(2\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}r^2(2\phi-\sin(2\phi)) $$

Comment: Clearly the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ are not directly known and must therefore be obtained as a function of $d$, $R$, and $r$. However, if $\theta$ and $\phi$ were known, then the formula for the area $A$ would also work in the case in which $d \geq R + r$ since at that point we would have $\theta = \phi = 0$ and therefore $A=0$. Similarly, I would like the formula to work also when $d \leq R - r$ and in particular in the limiting case $d=0$.

Comment: Is it possible through just knowing $d$, $R$, and $r$ to derive a formula that does not consider an "if-else" distinction? And if it is not possible, not knowing the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ directly, what information is needed?